# Убрать параметр id из url yii

Tags: yii

Здравствуйте. Есть url типа /index.php?r=post/view&id=1&title=abcd. Нужно сделать следующий url: /post/abcd.

В правилах urlManager выставляю:

```
'post/<title:.*?>'=>'items/view',
```

В итоге получается: /post/abcd?id=1

Возможно ли вообще убрать id из url. Есть ли да, то как?

Спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

Искать статью по названию не самая хорошая идея, я бы посоветовал добавить поле "uri" в таблицу с постами с уникальными значениями, которая хранила бы название название статьи в транскрипции замененными пробелы дефисом и удаленными знаками припенания

В правилах:

```
'post/<uri>' => 'item/view'
```

Во вьшках:

```
$this->createUrl('item/view',array('uri'=>$model->uri))
```

В экшине:

```
$model = Post::model()->find('uri = :uri', [':uri' => $uri]);
```

Таким образом получится урл /post/hello-world на статью с названием "Hollo world!!!"

П.С. могу чегонибудь напутать, сразу прошу прощения, давно не колупался в Yii, плотно занялся Yii2